# Android studio virtual machine is starting up？

Tags: android

The Android studio virtual machine is starting up, but the IDE always waiting for all target devices to come online.

[image]

[image]

Error running 'app':
Time out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

There is error log.
https://1drv.ms/t/s!ArfBkw103EmWhQrv2agkBU3VpwDF?e=X95loA

I have repeatedly installed the virtual machine multiple times, but there is no effect.

[image]

There are errors logs:

```
C:\Users\yuand\.android\avd>emulator -list-avds
Pixel

C:\Users\yuand\.android\avd>emulator -avd Pixel
INFO    | Android emulator version 33.1.24.0 (build_id 11237101) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | checking ANDROID_HOME for valid sdk root.
INFO    | checking ANDROID_SDK_ROOT for valid sdk root.
WARNING | ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is missing.
emulator: WARN: Cannot find valid sdk root from environment variable ANDROID_HOME nor ANDROID_SDK_ROOT,Try to infer from emulator's path
INFO    | guessed sdk root is D:\App
WARNING | platforms subdirectory is missing under D:\App, please install it
INFO    | guessed sdk root D:\App does not seem to be valid
INFO    | guessed sdk root is D:\
emulator: WARN: D:\ is not a directory, and canot be sdk root
INFO    | guessed sdk root D:\ does not seem to be valid
INFO    | guessed sdk root is .
WARNING | platforms subdirectory is missing under ., please install it
INFO    | guessed sdk root . does not seem to be valid
WARNING | invalid sdk root .
emulator: WARN: Cannot find valid sdk root path.
PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to Resolve Android Emulator problems :

1. open command prompt (terminal) at this location C:\Users{your_username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator.
2. Run below command with your already created emulator name:

- emulator.exe -avd Pixel_4_API_31 (Your emulater name)

3. in the commmand prompt you will get the problem why emulator is not starting.

Comment: I have already provided the error log. Could you provide more information on how to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: do the steps i mentioned in the command prompt you will get the problem. In my case a dll file was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating another AVD with following system Image

[image]

maybe your AVD Image is not compatible with your processor type.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. The software Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for Intel processors needs to be installed.

Comment: What is the "Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver" ? Do you have link, explaination or anything ? I suggest you to [edit] your answer to add more details